# setSupportActionBar not working on android 4.4

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat, android-toolbar

I'm trying to implement the navigation drawer example using the toolbar. I've referred the documentation link
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

but my app crashes at "setSupportActionBar".

Is there any option to make the toolbar work on previous android versions i.e 4.4,4.3 etc like the google apps i.e gmail, playstore etc

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: well what is the error

Comment: Make sure your activity extends `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: I've personally followed this and can claim it works **100%** on previous Android versions (up to 4.0 tested at least, with the same code, and should work farther back). Try to post some code, including your Activity, theme **files** (should have one for v21 and one for <v21), and xml for the Activity. Also, maybe post your dependencies in case, but that should be a more obvious issue. And finally, posting your error first will definitely help narrow things down

Comment: I m sorry. It is now working just needed to update the ADT plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

if it's the case, change

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

by

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: even if it is ok (don't know), please some explanatory text as to WHY -- like in school the solution alone isn't everything :)

Comment: I did'nt see he's already found the solution, so mine is useless. Otherwise, setSupportActionBar didn't work in my project with import android.widget.Toolbar, that why I changed it to import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Please see that these are included:

- import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
- import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
- class extends AppCompatActivity;
  (Also the appcompat.support library should be added in File->Project Structure-> Dependencies.)